# How to install Google Drive?

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to install Google Drive client in Freya. Does anyone knows a Google Drive client that supports elementary OS.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Google itselft doesn't provide a linux-client for Google Drive, but there are several third-party clients:

## Grive 2

[Grive 2](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2) is the fork of the original command line client [Grive](https://github.com/Grive/grive).
There are a few things that Grive does not do at the moment:

- continously wait for changes in file system or in Google Drive to occur and upload. A sync is only performed when you run Grive, and it calculates checksums for all files every time.
- symbolic links support.
- support for Google documents.

These may be added in the future, possibly the next release.

### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive
```

### Authorization

When Grive is run for the first time, you should use the `-a` argument to grant permission to Grive to access to your Google Drive.

```
mkdir -p ~/grive
cd ~/grive
grive -a
```

A URL should be printed. Go to the link. You will need to login to your Google account if you haven't done so. After granting the permission to Grive, the browser will show you an authenication code. Copy-and-paste that to the standard input of Grive.
If everything works fine, Grive will create `.grive` and `.grive_state` files in your current directory. It will also start downloading files from your Google Drive to your current directory.

---

## jdrivesync

[jdrivesync](https://github.com/siom79/jdrivesync) is a simple command line tool that synchronizes a local file system structure to your Google Drive.

### Features

- Scalability
- Multi-User
- Partial Sync
- Up or down synchronization
- Reporting
- No application-specific metadata

### Installation

Download the [latest released DEB](https://github.com/siom79/jdrivesync/releases) and install it manually.
Please note that jdrivesync requires openjdk-8-jre. How to install openjdk in version 8 for Ubuntu <14.10 is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts).

After successful installation you can start jdrivesync with:

```
/opt/jdrivesync/jdrivesync.sh
```

### Authorization

When you start jdrivesync for the first time it will print an authentication URL. You will have to point your browser to this URL, login with your Google account and grant jdrivesync the requested privileges. After having clicked on `Accept` you will be redirected to a new page that displays an authentication token. Copy this token to the command line and press Enter.

---

## google-drive-ocamlfuse

[google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) is a FUSE filesystem backed by Google Drive, written in OCaml. It lets you mount your Google Drive on Linux.

### Features

- Full read/write access to ordinary files and folders
- Read-only access to Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides (exported to configurable formats)
- Multiple account support
- Duplicate file handling
- Access to trash (.Trash directory)

### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

### Authorization

To understand how the authorization process works, and to discover all the available options, follow the instuctions at the [authorization page](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Authorization).

---

## Insync

[Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) is the most feature rich multi platform client for Google Drive.

Insync is not for free, a lifetime license per Google account costs [20$](https://www.insynchq.com/pricing). In my opinion it is totally worth it. I'm using this client for some time now, and it's working without any problems or hiccups.

Insync is going to add pantheon support soon (according to their support forums).

### Features

- Multiple accounts
- Convert Google Docs to Office
- Convert to OpenDocument
- Symlink, junction and alias
- External & network drives
- Desktop notifications
- Name your own folder
- Revert read-only files
- Feed of file changes
- Nested selective sync
- Preserve directory structure
- Ignore List

### Installation

```
wget -qO - https://d2t3ff60b2tol4.cloudfront.net/services@insynchq.com.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu trusty non-free contrib" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/insync-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install insync
```

### Authorization

The authorization is GUI driven and self-explanatory.

### elementary OS integration

I've created a complete set of matching icons (including indicator, mimetype, folder, emblems application icon) and pushed them to [elementary+](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus):
[image]
[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Excellent summary but note that Insync is now(Apr 2019) $29.99 for the prime edition. However, you can use multiple Google accounts (ie for home and work) and can install it on multiple devices. There is a "Team" version to sync Google Team Drives for $49.99.

Answer (score 1):

**OneGrive** : Google Drive Clint

Step 1:  [Download the latest version of overGrive DEB here.](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/public/overgrive/overgrive_3.1.2_all.deb&nid=168)

Step 2: Launch OneGrive

Step 3: A window will appear ,click on <kbd>Connect account</kbd> then a  browser window will open for you to `sign in` to your Google account.

Step 4: At the end you will get a **code** ,copy that code and paste it in the Onedrive window at **Account** entry box and click <kbd>validate</kbd>

Step 5: After setting your preferences (like location etc...) click <kbd>Start Sync</kbd>

For Reference [here](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive/installation-instructions-ubuntu)

Comment: Now call overGrive and require one license ($4.99) per Google Drive account.